# In Flutter, how do you set *all* the scaffold background color at once?

Tags: flutter, scaffold

Currently, I set background color of *each screen* using this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: ...
  );
```

Every time I create new screen, I always forgot to add this background color setter. This is a minor inconvenience, but I really appreciate if there's a method to set this background color once for all screens, unless overridden by `backgroundColor` property of specific `Scaffold`. I have tried to set the color on `MaterialApp`'s `color` property, but it doesn't look like it has any effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass custom ThemeData with background color parameter overwritten to you MaterialApp, so this will do the trick:

```
return MaterialApp(
        // your other app initialization code
        theme: ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
    );
```

You can read more about ThemData and flutter app theming in the official documentation
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

Comment: Umm, backgroundColor, or scaffoldBackgroundColor? Or doesn't matter which one?

Comment: yep, my bad, it should be scaffoldBackgroundColor.
The backgroundColor one is responsible for stuff like the remaining part of a progress bar (so only it is used only in some flutter widgets)

Comment: @ChenLiYong why dont you simply read [Scaffold.backgroundColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/backgroundColor.html) official docs?

Comment: @pskink because the one that's working for me is `scaffoldBackgroundColor`, and not `Scaffold.backgroundColor`.

Comment: @ChenLiYong and this is described in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/backgroundColor.html): *"backgroundColor property
Color backgroundColor
final
The color of the Material widget that underlies the entire Scaffold.

The theme's ThemeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor by default."*

Comment: @pskink and that is why I asked above, backgroundColor or scaffoldBackgroundColor, because I have just read that docs. Either way, I will accept the straightforward answer from Alexander.

Comment: @AlexanderMelnikov yep, no worries! Thank you for your help and confirmation!